# Help! My @font-face punctuation is floating up?

Tags: font-face, css, punctuation, vertical-alignment

So I have a typeface I've been including in a couple sites lately called Kondolar. It's a lovely typeface and I'm actually using 4 weights of the font, so there are actually 4 @font-face definitions in my stylesheet each with their own src files.

For reference, the sites are:
http://joelglovier.com, http://blog.joelglovier.com (tumblr's server) and http://hoverfx.com

So the issue I am coming across is that punctuation in these fonts is floating up to the middle of the text line, rather than being at the baseline for the font. I don't think it's an issue with the font itself, for two reasons:

1. the font does not display this
   behavior in Photoshop, InDesign,
   Illustrator, or any other software
   locally.
2. the really strange thing is that
   there is one location on one of
   those sites where the issue is not
   occuring: http://joelglovier.com in
   the intro copy at the very top of
   the page.

So I am leaning toward believing it is an issue with my styles, but after inspecting with Firebug and looking at all applied styles AS WELL AS computed styles, I just can't see what's causing it.

Further, there is one point that would lead me to think maybe it's an issue with the font file itself (point number two above not withstanding): I have another @font-face rule (yes, a 5th) for the font called League Gothic, and I'm not seeing the same issue with instances of that typeface on the page.

So what on earth is causing this floating punctuation?

**EDIT: It appears the characters affected are the period and colon. The question mark, dash and comman all appear to properly align with the font baseline.*

**Here's a screenshot: http://www.cl.ly/6tLs*

Comment: Looks fine in my FF4, IE8 and Chrome11. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 11, FF4 on OSX. Did you see the screenshot? You're not seeing the same thing as in the screenshot?

Comment: I checked the screenshot against what I see in my broswer for the "Hassisburg" section and it looks fine in my broser. I'm on a PC. Are you on Mac? Also, try uninstalling the font. You might be seeing a system font, where I am seeing the web font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as Nick suggested that my stylesheet must be calling the local copy of the font instead.

I tried the site on my windows virtual box, and as the question commenters have said, all looks well.